# Integrating/Using SOCKS5 proxies with UDP support into ENET

Tags: c++, udp, socks, enet

I am attemtping to integrate SOCKS5 support into a UDP protocol called ENET (http://enet.bespin.org/).
I have looked around at sending UDP traffic via SOCKS5 but could use some pointers as to how to go about settings this up in C++ Also, would it be easier to instead create a standalone application to route the traffic through in a different language?

I couldn't find a library that already implemented it, at least not specifically relating to enet, a seperate library for SOCKS5 UDP in C++ may exist though I suppose so if you know of one that would help. Apart from that I am unsure how I would have the ENET library integrate with code to route the UDP traffic through SOCKS5

Comment: I couldn't find a library that already implemented it, at least not specifically relating to enet, a seperate library for SOCKS5 UDP in C++ may exist though I suppose so if you know of one that would help. Apart from that I am unsure how I would have the ENET library integrate with code to route the UDP traffic through SOCKS5.

Comment: I've changed your question to add this missing detail. Next time please adjust your question yourself to provide the missing details.